# Reload only part of an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe

I looked on many posts but I've never found out such a context like the one I have so I'm requesting you some help.

Here is my development context :

I had in mind to build a **single-page based PHP Application** and I then chose to set-up a **global container** page embedding a **side navbar-menu on the left** for navigation control and an **iframe on the right** for related content. 
The iframe is updated following the navigation navbar to display the selected content to the user.

First, I'm not saying that this is the right way to do this kind of PHP Application and would be ears opened to different way to achieve this.

For now, it's working out but I rose up a problem since **I would like to reload only A PART of my content iframe**. Indeed, there is a div box inside it that should be updated when the rest shouldn't (or at least it looks strange during navigation).

I was wondering if setting-up a listener on the iframe to look on mysql database updates and then trigger a JS function would be memory cost efficient ? 
What would you guys think ? Maybe there's a different way to solve this problem (I was thinking of a big AJAX rendering instead of an iframe for example) ?

Thanks a lot for your answers,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so for those who would face the same situation I ended up trigerring an ajax function in my child iframe from the parent main page via the instruction `document.getElementbyId("myIframe").contentWindow.myAjaxFunction()` that run the search script in background (with post parameters from the parent page).

Then I got the reload of only a section of the iframe.